# Optimal schedule for a soccer tournament

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, recreational-mathematics

**Motivation.** This weekend, my children took part in a soccer tournament consisting of $n$ teams, each of which playing once against every other team. As there was only one soccer field, the schedule consisted of $n\choose 2$ games played one after the other. Some teams protested that they were scheduled to play in two successive games. Others complained about having to wait for a long time between two successive games.

This made me wonder whether an optimal schedule could be constructed, meaning that for every team the intervals between successive games are almost the same.

**Formalisation.** If $n$ is a positive integer, let $\text{enum}(n) := \{0, \ldots, n-1\}$. If $X$ is a set, let $[X]^2 := \big\{\{x,y\}: x\neq y\in X\big\}$. For the following, we interpret $n$ as the number of teams, $\text{enum}(n)$ as the set of teams, $[\text{enum}(n)]^2$ as the collection of all team pairings, and $\text{enum}{n\choose 2}$ as the set of game slots.  A *schedule for $n$ teams* is a bijection $$\sigma: \text{enum}{n\choose 2} \to [\text{enum}(n)]^2.$$

For any team $t\in\text{enum}(n)$, the *set of game slots of $t$* is defined as $$\text{sl}(t) = \sigma^{-1}\big(\{g \in [\text{enum}(n)]^2 : t\in g\}\big).$$

Note that $\text{sl}(t) \subseteq \text{enum}{n\choose 2}$ consists of exactly $n-1$: the slots of games that $t$ is playing, and $t$ plays against everyone else exactly once. We order $\text{sl}(t)$ recursively by setting

- $\text{sl}(t)_0 = \min \text{sl}(t)$, and
- $\text{sl}(t)_{k} = \min\{x\in \text{sl}(t): x > \text{sl}(t)_{k-1}$ for all $k\in \{1,\ldots,n-1\}$.

So $\text{sl}(t)_k$ is the slot number of game $k$ of team $t$.

Let $\text{ovmin}(\sigma)$ be the *overall minimum* of all breaks that any team has in consecutive games, that is $\text{ovmin}(\sigma) = \min\{\text{sl}(t)_{k+1} - \text{sl}(t)_k: t\in\text{enum}(n), 0\leq k < n-1\}.$ The *overall maximum* of all breaks that any team has in consecutive games, $\text{ovmax}(\sigma)$ is defined by replacing $\min$ by $\max$.

Let $\text{BESTMIN}(n)$ be the **maximum** of all $\text{ovmin}(\sigma)$ where $\sigma$ ranges over all schedules $\sigma: \text{enum}{n\choose 2} \to [\text{enum}(n)]^2$ and let $\text{BESTMAX}(n)$ be the **minimum** of all $\text{ovmax}(\sigma)$ where $\sigma$ ranges over all schedules $\sigma: \text{enum}{n\choose 2} \to [\text{enum}(n)]^2$. (So, both terms are typical min-max definitions.)

**Question.** Given a positive integer $n$, is there a "super schedule" $\sigma^*: \text{enum}{n\choose 2} \to [\text{enum}(n)]^2$ such that $\text{ovmin}(\sigma^*) = \text{BESTMIN}(n)$ and $\text{ovmax}(\sigma^*) = \text{BESTMAX}(n)$?

Also, it would be of interest to get estimations (or exact values) for $\text{BESTMIN}(n)$ and $\text{BESTMAX}(n)$ in terms of $n$, but this is not necessary for the acceptance of the answer.

**Acknowledgement.** Thanks to @LeechLattice for spotting an error in the definition of $\text{ovmax}(\cdot)$.

Comment: You assume that exactly one game is played on each day, right?

Comment: Thanks for your question @fedja, that's correct, there are no parallel games. So for game number $0$ we look at the schedule  $\sigma(0) \in [\text{enum}(n)]^2$, which has the form $\sigma(0) = \{a,b\}$, which means that game number $0$ is played between teams $a$ and $b$. Then for the next game, played after game number $0$ we have  $\sigma(1) = \{c,d\}$ for some $c,d$, and that game is between teams $c$ and $d$, and so on.

Comment: Are you sure that $\text {ovmax}(\sigma )$ is the maximum of all breaks that any team has in consecutive games?

Comment: Good point, thanks @LeechLattice! It's actually wrong that $\text{ovmax}(\sigma)$ is the maximum of all breaks that any team has in consecutive games. I need to reformulate $\text{ovmax}(\sigma)$. Will sit down with paper & pencil and edit the post as soon as I (think I) found the correct definition of $\text{ovmax}(\sigma)$.

Comment: I introduced consecutive slots and hope the definitions of both $\text{ovmin}(\sigma)$ and $\text{ovmax}(\sigma)$ work that way. Thanks again to @LeechLattice

Comment: It's easy to prove that $\textrm{BESTMIN}(n) \le \lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor$. I conjecture that this is tight, that $\textrm{BESTMAX}(n) = \lfloor \frac{n+2}{2} \rfloor$, and that there is a super schedule; but I've so far only managed to test it up to $n=7$.

Comment: Especially the modified strategy of David Speyer for even $n=2k$ realises $ovmin=k-1$ and $ovmax=k+1$. So Peter Taylors bounds are sharp and this is a super schedule for even $n$.

Comment: I'm curious why we don't define ovmax in terms of the *longest consecutive stretch of matches in which team t does not play.* (Or equivalently, set sl(t)_0 = 0 and sl(t)_n = nC2 + 1 for all t; eg for opening and closing ceremonies). This feels like a more natural translation of the original problem: under the current setup, a schedule which puts all of one team's games at the very end could have very small ovmax, when in reality the team in question would be pretty upset at having to wait so long before playing. (It's also easier to prove bounds on bestmax using the new definition.)

Comment: @JonathanLove, a schedule which puts all of one team's games at the very end gives a big ovmax because the teams which played the first match also need to play that team.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes but can't the remaining teams have the rest of their matches fairly well-distributed? In particular, if you design an n-person tournament in which no team has to wait more than n matches (including at the end), and then have each team play the (n+1)st team at the very end, the new ovmax should be < 2n, but team n+1 has to wait on the order of n^2 matches before they can play. So ovmax is really not doing a good job of capturing wait time.

Comment: In fact it's easy to design such a schedule with ovmax = n. So yes, big compared to the predicted optimum ≈ n/2, but far below the (n^2-n)/2 games one team has to wait. It's true this example won't be a super schedule, but what if we found a schedule with ovmin=BESTMIN and ovmax=BESTMAX, but this schedule requires one team to wait, say, 3n turns before first playing, while there are other schedules with no wait (including at beginning and end) longer than n/2+2. Should this schedule really be considered optimal? @DominicvanderZypen which option most closely addresses your original musings?

Comment: @JonathanLove Thanks for your thoughts on the definition of  ovmax. Your definition is exactly what I had in mind, I have to check whether I made a formal error and will try to mend it.

Comment: Thanks for putting in such an effort, everyone! As many contributed towards finding an optimal schedule, I would have wished to be able to accept several answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a streamlined description of the optimal strategies that have been found. In both strategies, there is a team that plays a special role -- call them $x$ -- and the other teams are numbered modulo $n-1$.

---

With $n=2k$ teams: We play $2k-1$ rounds of $k$ games each. In the $i$-th round, the games are
$$(x,i), (i-1,i+1), (i-2, i+2), \ldots, (i-k+1, i+k-1).$$
Team $x$ always waits $k$ games between playing; every other team either waits $k-1$ or $k+1$ games. (Here I mean the difference between time slots: If team $x$ plays at time $t$, then they play again at time $t+k$.)

---

With $n=2k+1$ teams: We play $2k$ rounds which are alternately "long" ($k+1$ games) and "short" ($k$ games), starting with a long round. In the $i$-th long round, the games are
$$(x,i), (i+1,i-1), (i+2, i-2), \ldots, (i+k-1, i-k+1), (i+k, x).$$
In the $i$-th short round, the games are
$$(i,i+1), (i-1, i+2), (i-2, i+3), \ldots, (i-k+1, i+k).$$
Every wait is either $k$ or $k+1$ games.

---

I wish I had time to make some animated graphics of these. I'd put players $1$ through $n-1$ around a circle and $x$ at the center, and draw lines between the pairs as they occur.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a first attempt, for others to improve on. For simplicity, I'll take $n=2k+1$ to be odd. We index the teams by integers modulo $n$.

We'll schedule $n$ rounds of $k$ games each. In the $j$-th round, the games (in order) are
$$ \{ j+1, j-1 \},\  \{ j+2, j-2 \},\  \{ j+3, j-3 \},\ \ldots,\ \{ j+k, j-k \}$$
and team $j$ sits out.

The longest break between games is $2k$ games (team $j$ plays the first game in the $(j-1)$-st round, sits out the $j$-th round and plays the first game in the $(j+1)$-st round). All the other breaks are either $k-1$ or $k+1$ games. So the ratio between longest break and shortest break is $\approx 2$.

I bet we can get that ratio down to $1+o(1)$. What solutions have other people found?

Comment: This strategy can be visualized quite beautifully by turning the soccer tournament to a chess tournament. Suppose you have a long table with k chessboards. Then the 2k+1 players are placed around the table, the one extra player sits at the end of the table. Then after each round everybody gets up and moves one board to his/her left. When all players are back in their starting positions, everybody has played everybody else exactly one.

Comment: @HenrikRüping Yup, that's how I visualized it! But, in the chess setting, it makes sense to play $k$ games at once. In this problem, you have to figure out which order the $k$ games should be played in for each seating. My intuition is that, if you are smart about this, you can get the longest wait to be $k+O(1)$, but I always wound up with a $2k$ wait somewhere, so I decided to just post what I had.

Comment: Odd $n$ seems to be harder because there's less margin between min and max. Up to relabelling of the teams there's one solution for $n=3$ and two each for $n \in \{5, 7\}$. If there's a pattern which can be extrapolated to larger odd $n$ then I haven't yet seen it, but feel free to try. Data at https://gist.github.com/pjt33/b055e3d5c87478d73bde7b5199b9f91a

Comment: Aha! Looking at the deltas for each team there's a fairly straightforward pattern. Need to prove it works, but empirically it gives a solution for odd $n$ up to $n=25$.

Comment: By the way, the analogous strategy for even $n$ gives ga maximal waiting time of $n+O(1)$. Here you pick one of the $2k+2$ players that always plays against the one sitting at the end of the table. Then just play all games in one round from one end of the table to the other and repeat with the next round.

Comment: @HenrikRüping Nice! You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

For even $n=2k$ there is such a super-schedule. As Peter Taylor wrote, it should be easy to prove that $BESTMIN \le k-1$ and $BESTMAX\ge k+1$. Writing down a schedule with $ovmin=k-1$ and $ovmax=k+1$ thus means, that it is a super-schedule and that both bounds are sharp.

The idea is to think of it as a chess tournament, e.g. think of a long table (say from left to right) with $k$ chess boards. The idea is that one fixed player always stays at the leftmost board, while the other players (after each round is finished) move to their left around the table (and skip the fixed player). In this model the games are played simultaneously, while in the question they are played sequentially (e.g. we have only one board).

Thus we start from left to right and play the leftmost game first until that round is finished and we start with the next round.

Let us now figure out how long the breaks are. If a player sits at board $m$ in some round, then in the next round he sits at one of the boards $m-1,m,m+1$. Thus he always has a break of $k-1,k,k+1$ games. This shows that $ovmin=k-1$ and $ovmax=k+1$ and thus this is a super-schedule and the bounds are sharp.

The case of odd n remains open.

Comment: Correction: I didn't claim that it should be easy to prove the bound on BESTMAX. For BESTMIN it's a simple contradiction: if $n=2k$ and $\text{ovmin}(\sigma) \ge k$ then no team can play twice in the first $k$ matches, and the only teams which can play in the $(k+1)$st match (and that only if $\text{ovmin}(\sigma) = k$) are the teams which already met in the first match, violating the tournament structure. For BESTMAX we can show that the teams which play in the first match can't play in the last $n-2$ matches, but that doesn't look restrictive enough.

Comment: Isn't it pretty much the same argument for BESTMAX ? If $ovmax(\sigma)=k$ then no team can play twice in the first $k$ games (since then there would be one team which does not play and it would have an initial break of $k+1$ games) and then in the $k+1$-st games the two teams from the first match cannot play against each other, so that one of them has a break of length $k+1$.

Comment: No. The definition of $\text{ovmax}$ doesn't count the matches before a team's first match as a break.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: this is a partial answer which expands on some comments I've made on the question and on the earlier answers.

#### Bounds

Theorem: $\textrm{BESTMIN}(n) \le \lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor$
Proof: consider first the case of odd $n = 2k+1$. Suppose $\text{ovmin}(\sigma) > k$. Then no team can play twice in the first $k+1$ matches. But that requires $2k+2$ distinct teams, giving a contradiction. For even $n$ the argument is similar. If $n=2k$ and $\text{ovmin}(\sigma) \ge k$ then no team can play twice in the first $k$ matches, and the only teams which can play in the $(k+1)$st match (and that only if $\text{ovmin}(\sigma) = k$) are the teams which already met in the first match, violating the tournament structure and giving a contradiction. $\blacksquare$

Conjecture: $\textrm{BESTMAX}(n) = \lfloor \frac{n+2}{2} \rfloor$
An argument along similar lines doesn't seem so promising. Consider the case $n = 2k+1$. Suppose $\text{ovmax}(\sigma) \le k$. Then a team whose first match has index $i$ must play all $n-1$ matches by the end of match $i + (n-2)\operatorname{ovmax}(\sigma) \le i + (n-2)k$. Note that there are a total of $\frac{n(n-1)}2 = nk$ matches. So the two teams which play in the first match can't play in the last $2k-1$ matches. But can we have $O(\sqrt n)$ teams play the first $n$ matches, $O(\sqrt n)$ teams play the last $n$ matches, and nullify the problem?

---

#### Tournament for odd number of teams

I claim that the following slot assignment gives a tournament for $n = 2k+1$ teams with $\text{ovmin}(\sigma) = k$ and $\text{ovmax}(\sigma) = k+1$. This is optimal for $\text{ovmin}$ and for $\text{ovmax} - \text{ovmin}$.

$$\text{sl}(t) = \begin{cases}
 \{ \lfloor \frac{jn}2 \rfloor : 0 \le j < n-1 \} & \textrm{if } t = 0 \\
 \{\frac{t-1}2 + j(k+1) - \max(0, j+t-n) : 0 \le j < n-1 \} & \textrm{if } t \equiv 1 \pmod 2 \\
 \{\frac t2 + jk + \max(0, j-t): 0 \le j < n - 1\} & \textrm{if } 2 \le t \wedge t \equiv 0 \pmod 2 \\
\end{cases}$$

The slots can be seen to stay in the range $[0, nk-1]$ so by the pigeonhole principle it suffices to show (a) that each pair of teams meets and (b) that each slot is used at most twice.

Absent a more elegant idea, (a) can be done by case analysis. I present a simple table without proofs: the proof of each case is straightforward.

$$\begin{array}[8]{cccccccc}
t & u & \text{Condition} & & & & & \\
0 & 1 & & \operatorname{sl}(t)[0] & = & \operatorname{sl}(u)[0] & = & 0 \\
0 & 2m+1 & m > 0 & \operatorname{sl}(t)[n-u+1] & = & \operatorname{sl}(u)[n-u] & = & \frac{n(n-u+1)-1}{2} \\
0 & 2m & m > 0 & \operatorname{sl}(t)[u] & = & \operatorname{sl}(u)[u] & = & mn \\
2\ell + 1 & 2m+1 & m > \ell & \operatorname{sl}(t)[n - \ell - m - 1] & = & \operatorname{sl}(u)[n - \ell - m - 1] & = & (n - \ell - m - 1)(k+1) + \ell \\
2\ell + 1 & 2m & m < \ell & \operatorname{sl}(t)[n - \ell + m - 1] & = & \operatorname{sl}(u)[n - \ell + m - 1] & = & (n - \ell + m - 1)(k+1) - m \\
2\ell + 1 & 2m & m \ge \ell & \operatorname{sl}(t)[m - \ell] & = & \operatorname{sl}(u)[m - \ell] & = & m + (m - \ell)k \\
2\ell & 2m & m > \ell & \operatorname{sl}(t)[m+\ell] & = & \operatorname{sl}(u)[m+\ell] & = & m + (m+\ell)k \\
\end{array}$$

I think (b) could be shown by a further pairwise case analysis, but I suspect that someone else will be able to spot a more elegant reformulation of the tournament which renders it considerably less tedious, so I'm posting as a partial answer.